# How to choose an index

Tags: sql

Can anyone explain and answer the following questions to me? I am having trouble understanding them. Really appreciate for your help

Choose an index for each of the following SELECT statements. Specify whether your choice is clustered or unclustered and whether it is a hash index or a B+ tree.

```
a. SELECT S.Name
FROM Student S
WHERE S.Id = ’111111111’

b. SELECT S.Name
FROM Student S
WHERE S.Status = ’Freshman’

c. SELECT T.StudId
FROM Transcript T
WHERE T.Grade = ’B’ AND T.CrsCode = ’CS305’

d. SELECT P.Name
FROM Professor P
WHERE P.Salary BETWEEN 20000 AND 150000

e. SELECT T.ProfId
FROM Teaching T
WHERE T.CrsCode LIKE ’CS%’ AND T.Semester = ’F2000’
```

I really qppreciate for all of your comments, I don't have any experience related to this topic, I am just reading a book and am would like to know how to do the following questions. It is for self-learning not for a school homework.

Comment: you need to attempt your own homework, and ask when you get stuck. Unless you show your willingness to attempt these, I doubt anyone is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: It's one thing to ask a question about something you need help with, it's another to dump a homework assignment here and tell us to do the whole thing for you.

Comment: How big are each of the tables?  It tends to work out that clustering vs non-clustering is irrelevant when the tables are small, for a rather vague definition of small that almost certainly includes any sample DB you get to play with.

Comment: Amongst other books, you could try [Relational Database Index Design and the Optimizers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471719994).  You could also try searching for ideas in other questions about index design (for instance, [SO 523018](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523018/when-should-you-consider-indexing-your-sql-tables/), which also contains x-refs to other questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply your knowledge of what indexes are and how they work to each scenario - in most real-world situations its not possible to know exactly what indexes are needed without testing using representative data, but you can usually come up with a good guess as to what the optimal indexes will be - especially with the relatively simple examples you have posted.

Read up some more on indexes and then for each question think carefully about **what columns are involved** and how the results will be filtered.

There are plenty of resources on indexes available via Google, [An Introduction to Clustered and Non-Clustered Index Data Structures](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/index_data_structures_p1.aspx) looks like a good starting point.

If you need any further help then you will be best served by posting **specific** questions about specific examples.